# Kubernetes service unable to access s3 with Istio sidecar

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, kubernetes, istio

Just wondering if anyone has any luck/solution when using AWS SDK to access AWS resource such as S3 when service injected with Istio sidecar.

As Istio's [document](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/traffic-rules/egress-rules.html) points out:

1. traffic will go through Istio sidecar, you will need white list the DNS or IPs.
2. https is not available. Can only do by changing the format to something like "http://www.google.com:443"

However, AWS SDK handles the https connection hence I can't rewrite the URL. Subsequently, I'll get an "http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client" error.

Many thanks.

Comment: Just found one solution: using istioctl and --includeIPRanges, such as deploy using "kubectl apply -f <(istioctl kube-inject -f samples/sleep/sleep.yaml --includeIPRanges=10.0.0.1/24)" Not elegant though.

Comment: You wrote: "...I can't rewrite the URL. Subsequently, I'll get an "http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client" error." So did you manage to change the URL to "http://...:443" ?